# Why do PayPal API credentials (client id and secret) need to be secure

Tags: security, paypal, oauth-2.0, express-checkout

I'm currently implementing PayPal Express Checkout, and I know that the PayPal API credentials need to be kept secure. But if they were somehow exposed to the outside world, what could an attacker do to a merchant account, and what is the worst that could happen?

Answer (score 1):

The attacker could operate the account. Worse, he would operate it as you, so your customer will see it as your fault. Which is exactly what it would be.

Comment: Agreed, but what more could they do over and above operating as a middleman between some customer and your paypal account? They can't access funds, but can they access things like transaction histories? (I'm still learning the ins and outs of the API).

Comment: Operating as a middleman between *your* customer and *his* Paypal account, you mean.

Comment: Aren't the API credentials tied to your PayPal merchant account? So if they are used to form a payment and execute it, it is to your account?

Comment: Or do you mean that an attacker could inject their credentials at the insecure point? If so, what malicious actions could they do using *just* your credentials?

Comment: They can perform the same actions that you can, and they will look like you when they do so, so you're the one who's liable. I started out by referring to the case where the developer and the account-holder aren't the same person, which is the purpose of API keys, but if it's your account it's even worse, as you not only bear the liablity but you also lose any money involved.

Comment: Learning about the associated liability is certainly beneficial; though I was more interested in the extent of what can be performed through the PayPal API (such as what an attacker could do using your specific API credentials). Though I guess I need to spend more time learning the API capabilities.

Comment: To my understanding client id does not need to be secure. In particular, it is put into react frontend. Please correct me if I am wrong.